# How are the bank's "voiceprint" authentication methods secure?

Tags: banks, biometrics, scam

A few years ago, an agent from the bank rang up to say my credit card was compromised.  But first they wanted me to confirm who I was.  I refused, they were ringing from a private number, they could be scammers, gathering my security questions, date of birth etc.  Later when the card actually stopped and they rang I agreed to go through with it.

It happened again yesterday. I was steeling myself to refuse to give any information away.  But they have a new system using voice print.  You say the phrase `my voice confirms my identity`, which I had recorded with them before.  Thinking, this was safer, I voiced the phrase.

But really, they could have been scammers trying to get my voiceprint.

How is this process secure if the bank has not proven to me that they are genuine?

Comment: It is not. You should hang up and call the bank back at the number on your card.

Answer (score 1):

This process authenticates you to them, not the other way around. And the process is secure for them because:

- if scammers record that phrase to play back to the bank, it will be different than the voice they used to answer the call
- the scammers would also need to have your phone
- it's the bank that's calling the account holder

So, from their perspective, it's two-factor authentication with a sanity check on the voice. They initiate the process, which offers the same assurance as it does when you call them. If you initiate the call, then they lose a factor.

And this all gets defeated with AI voice changers, but that's a tomorrow problem.

Comment: "that's a tomorrow problem"... literally tomorrow...

Comment: The problem is though that most of the current scams (around here anyway) are based on this.  The scammers calling people pretending to be the bank, and people give out there details.  I have tried telling the bank this.  But I suspect that they somehow benefit from fraud.  Otherwise they could really reduce it quickly.

Comment: @RohitGupta that's pure speculation that the banks benefit, and if you believe that, then your question is moot. But your question is about which process is secure. What you don't specify is "secure for ***whom?***. This is a secure process for the bank. It is not secure for ***you***. For a secure process for you, use their website or call them.

Comment: @ThoriumBR that's why I didn't say it was a "future" problem :)

Comment: @schroeder that comment was flippant. It wasn't part of the question. Calling a bank or any support and hanging on the line for minutes to hours is not practical.